# c - how to make a function with multiple arguments (va_list)?

Tags: c, arguments, xcode4.3, variadic-functions

I have a nice C++ function, which supports multiple arguments through va_list + va_start + va_arg.
But I had to convert my project to C. After conversion, this va_list construction gets rejected by the compiler (multiple errors). Is there any way to do that thing in C, and (if yes) what I need to change?

Comment: Please show the code you're using, and the exact error messages you're getting.

Comment: For start, we need to have a look at your code and the errors that the compiler complains about. Without this information we're helpless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Wikipedia page on [stdarg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdarg.h) has probably everything you need.